# calling a function using string in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to find a way to call a function by typing its name in a text box and clicking a button , i have 417 functions and they don't take any variables

for example i want to type in a textbox

```
listproducts
```

and click a button

then `listproducts()` will get called.

is it possible to do such things without using select case or if statements?
or is it possible to assign a string name to a function and call it by that name?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reflection.  Assuming the the functions you want to call are all static methods on a class called `Foo` you can do something like this.

```
Dim functionName as String = "listproducts"
Dim fooType As System.Type = GetType(Foo)
Dim Method As System.MethodInfo = fooType.GetMethod(functionName)
Method.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```